# bug report: logging in via delegated OpenID

Tags: bug, login, openid

### description

Logging in via a delegated OpenID on a server with an IP dual stack does not work.

### to reproduce

Go to log in page, expand `more login options` and enter the OpenID. The web server for the domain listens on `[::]:80` and `[::]:443`.

### expected result

Redirect to the delegate provider.

Adds a line like `198.252.206.71 - - [28/Jun/2016:05:28:36 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 844 "-" "DotNetOpenAuth.Core/4.3.4.13329"` in the web server's access log.

### actual result

[image]

Shows the erroneous error message `No OpenID endpoint found.`.

Web server does not record any HTTP request from Stack Exchange to detect the delegate.